# MediaPlayer playback limit

Tags: android, audio, playback

I'm using a MediaPlayer to play my sound effects but after a certain point (28 playbacks to be exact) the MediaPlayer does not play anymore. This is how I create the MediaPlayer:

```
if(noteManager.rep.get((layer)).notes[j] == 0){
      MediaPlayer mp;
      switch (j){
          case 0:
               mp = MediaPlayer.create(InGame.this, R.raw.one);
               break;
          ...
      }}
```

Right after I call:

```
mp.start();
```

Also, this code gets executed a couple times a second. It all works fine until the 29th sound effect, after which it stops working (there's no sound). I'm using short wav files. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you stopping and releasing previous `MediaPlayer` instances before creating new ones? Either way, this seems like something a [`SoundPool`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) would be better suited for.

Comment: No I'm not calling stop at any point. I don't want to stop them because they aren't done by the time the next starts to play. Basically 6 play in rapid succession. And the fifth time through it starts acting up. I'll take a look at SoundPool too

Comment: For playing sounds and not music, you should be using SoundPool, not MediaPlayer. SoundPool also works with looping as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Use MediaPlayer outside the click event**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ImageView Reload;
private TextView Label;
private MediaPlayer mp;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Reload = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_Reload);
    Label = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_appname);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.reloadsound);
    Reload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                v.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.iv_anim));
                mp.start();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment.